# GitHub : 2 users working on 1 repository of any organization

Tags: github

I have some queries with following scenario on github.

consider there is one organization who have created repository "repo1" and added 2 users in their organization to work on that repository.

Now every user had taken clone of that and make changes in common file and commit their changes so it will make changes in their local copy (as i understood) , now when they will push, at that time **how github will merge their changes? how conflicts will be handled?**

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub will reject non fast-forward pushes by default. This means, that unless the user does a `git pull` to resolve the conflict locally, the push will fail. Git does The Right Thing™, you won't overwrite changes.